# Bitbucket pipleline python3.7 not found! Try the pythonBin option

Tags: python, aws-lambda, serverless-framework, bitbucket-pipelines

I have below bitbucket pipeline

```
    image: node:11.13.0-alpine

pipelines:
  branches:
    master:
      - step:
          caches:
            - node
          script:
            - apk add python py-pip python3
            - npm install -g serverless
            - serverless config credentials --stage dev --provider aws --key $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID --secret $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
            - cd src/rsc_user
            - pip install -r requirements.txt
            - sls plugin install -n serverless-python-requirements
            - sls plugin install -n serverless-wsgi
            - npm i serverless-package-external --save-dev
            - npm install serverless-domain-manager --save-dev
            - serverless deploy --stage dev
```

Throwing error

> ```
>  Error --------------------------------------------------
> Error: python3.7 not found! Try the pythonBin option.
>   at pipAcceptsSystem (/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/src/rsc_user/node_modules/serverless-python-requirements/lib/pip.js:100:13)
>   at installRequirements (/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/src/rsc_user/node_modules/serverless-python-requirements/lib/pip.js:173:9)
>   at installRequirementsIfNeeded (/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/src/rsc_user/node_modules/serverless-python-requirements/lib/pip.js:556:3)
>   at ServerlessPythonRequirements.installAllRequirements (/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/src/rsc_user/node_modules/serverless-python-requirements/lib/pip.js:635:29)
>   at ServerlessPythonRequirements.tryCatcher (/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/src/rsc_user/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
>   at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/src/rsc_user/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:547:31)
>   at Promise._settlePromise (/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/src/rsc_user/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:604:18)
>   at Promise._settlePromise0 (/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/src/rsc_user/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:649:10)
>   at Promise._settlePromises (/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/src/rsc_user/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:729:18)
>   at _drainQueueStep (/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/src/rsc_user/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:93:12)
>   at _drainQueue (/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/src/rsc_user/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:86:9)
>   at Async._drainQueues (/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/src/rsc_user/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:102:5)
>   at Immediate.Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate] (/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/src/rsc_user/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:15:14)
>   at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:443:21)
>   at process.topLevelDomainCallback (domain.js:136:23)
>
>  For debugging logs, run again after setting the "SLS_DEBUG=*" environment variable.
> Get Support --------------------------------------------
>  Docs:          docs.serverless.com
>  Bugs:          github.com/serverless/serverless/issues
>  Issues:        forum.serverless.com
> Your Environment Information ---------------------------
>  Operating System:          linux
>  Node Version:              11.13.0
>  Framework Version:         2.1.1
>  Plugin Version:            4.0.4
>  SDK Version:               2.3.2
>  Components Version:        3.1.4
> ```

I am not able to get this error as I am new in python.
any help highly appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This error basically means you do not have the *right* installation of python. Some application needs python3.7 and you do not specify a version with `apk add python3`. Hence, the latest is probably installed (3.8).

This [article](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/python-with-bitbucket-pipelines/) deals with how to select a given python version for an agent in a bitbucket pipeline. It basically boils down to:

```
image: python:3.7
pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        script:
          - python --version
```

Is there a reason you have to use Alpine? Otherwise I'd go for the pragmatic image above.

Comment: I have just started working in python, I am not getting how this is related to python installed on my local machine. This is running in bitbucket pipeline

Comment: when I added apk add python3.7 it says "ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints:
  python3.7 (missing):"

Comment: So your bitbucket pipeline runs your pipeline on an agent. If that agent does not have the right tools installed you will see errors like these. I'll ammend my answer for clarity.

Comment: If you want an alpine/python combination those are always available. See the [docker public registry](https://hub.docker.com/_/python).

Comment: sorry for stupidity qeustions... should I replace  node:11.13.0-alpine with " node:11.13.0-alpine:3.11", actually I am doing this first time so very confused or "python:11.13.0-alpine:3.11"

Comment: https://hub.docker.com/r/sitapati/docker-alpine-python-node this one might do it?

Answer (score 0):

he solve with

```
pythonRequirements:
   pythonBin: python3
```

[Similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65016106/4450951)